# Why Laravel 7 takes exactly 1 minute delay in sending an email using g-suite (gmail) services hosted on godaddy linux deluxe package

Tags: laravel, gmail

I easily send instantaneous emails from my Laravel app when running locally. But when the app is hosted on Godaddy (delux linux + c-panel package) using the following credentials (as suggested by Godaddy, I can't get rid of this 1-minute delay in receiving the message.

MAIL_DRIVER=smtp

MAIL_HOST=localhost

MAIL_PORT=25

MAIL_USERNAME=

MAIL_PASSWORD=

MAIL_ENCRYPTION=

I also tried sending using sendmail driver and get same result.

I am using the g-suite email services and have checked with google support that the mx records are ok. Webmail is also normally quick.

Please help :)

Comment: Are you owner of the code? Sounds like on production a queue is being used (which could explain the 1 minute interval).